# How to send html page as message when sending email in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send a html page as message when sending email in codeigniter..

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->from('xyz@gmail.com', 'ABC');
$this->email->to($this->input->post('emailid'));            
$this->email->subject('New Subject');   

$message = //HERE I WANT TO INCLUDE A FILE TO END AS MESSAGE    

$this->email->message($message);        
$this->email->send();
```

Could it be possible ??
Please help...

Comment: [Check this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data): `$emailTemplate = $this->load->view('email/template', $data, true);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the method [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$message = file_get_contents("/path/to/htmlfile");
```

Also you can use the [codeigniter way](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data)

```
$template = $this->load->view(APPATH.'email/file', $your_data, true);
```

Comment: Thank u sir... emailContent.php is the file i want to send... its in the views folder... when i used this file_get_contents('/application/views/emailContent.php'); its not working...

Comment: does your file is static or has any variables? because you asked in question to load a html file

Comment: How to call that particular name of the file in file_get_contents ??

Comment: explain or show your emailContent.php. it may contain any variable which have to pass from your controller to view.

Comment: "file_get_contents('/application/views/emailContent.php'); its not working..." because you have to include correct path, set it as `file_get_contents(APPPATH.'views/emailContent.php');` or even better load view file as shown already.

Answer (score 0):

What I have been using in my project, I created a function in a common_helper named as **sendMail**

```
function sendMail($subject, $mailContent, $mailTo, $mailFromId, $mailFromName)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('email');
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $CI->email->clear(TRUE);
    $CI->email->initialize($config);
    $CI->email->from($mailFromId, $mailFromName);
    $CI->email->to($mailTo);
    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($mailContent);
    $CI->email->send();
}
```

You can call this function anywhere from your controller to send mail. Regarding HTML content of email should be loaded as Agam Banga mentioned above:

```
$mailContent = $this->load->view('email/template', $data, true);
```

This varibale can be passed simply calling like

```
sendMail($subject, $mailContent, $mailTo, $mailFromId, $mailFromName);
```

In your controller.

Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here the code of Model and sending mail Using Email Library. And auto load library use it on your config folder -> autoload file
$autoload['libraries'] = array('email');

public function mail_send($mdata){

```
          $this->load->library('email');
          $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
         //$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
          $this->email->from($mdata['email']); // change it to yours
          $this->email->to('xyz@gmail.com');// change it to yours
          $this->email->cc($mdata['email']);
          $this->email->subject('Hello');
          //$this->email->message($mdata['address']);

          $body= $this->load->view('pages/mail', $mdata, true);
          $this->email->message($body);
          // echo '<pre>';
          // print_r($mdata);
          // exit();

          $this->email->send();


          $this->email->clear();
```

}